# Java Repaint method creates new objects on top of old ones

Tags: java, draw, actionlistener, repaint, paintcomponent

This is probably a stupid question but I can not seem to either remember how to stop the program from doing this or I never learned it.

I'm creating a blackjack game which draws random cards with the paintComponent.  When the hit button is clicked, I want it to draw the next card and generate the new total.  However, whenever I click the hit button, it draws the new card perfect, but it then creates all new cards on top of my already drawn cards.

How do I stop the repaint method from picking new random cards and keep them the same throughout the program?  I should mention, all the cards are stored in an array and are called to with a random number generator.  Also, this happens when I resize the java window.

If asked, I will post the code but I feel like this has a simple solution.

Comment: Do you have the "select random card logic" code inside the `paintComponent()` method, along with your actual painting code?

Comment: Yes I do, I'm guessing I should move the code to outside of it?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. Are you saying that, for example, you have 2 cards which are 4diamond and 2heart, and when you 'hit' to obtain a 3rd card, the values of the original 2 cards change to something different?

Comment: WATTO: Yes, I'm saying I had a 4Diamond and 2Heart drawn, but when I hit repaint, a 8Spaids and 9Clubs drew over the first two.  Greg: You are awesome, that fixed it, I don't know why I didn't think of that but thank you so much.  I sat her for almost 3 hours trying different things.  I know that's pathetic, but thank you!!!!

Comment: you shouldn't do the drawing a random card inside of `paintComponent()` try moving that outside (to an `actionListener` seems to make the most sense) and see what happens.

Comment: So that you can learn from this, `paintComponent()` will be invoked automatically by Swing when ever it needs to paint the component - this includes if some other window obscures your component.  As such, you don't want to have any "logic" that mutates your comonent state in there -- `paintComponent()` should just draw the component, based on the component's state.  Your mutation logic should be elsewhere, like an action listener (which is only invoked in response to user input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to move your 'select random card' logic outside of the paint method.

It might be a better idea to calculate all the cards in your array when you first build it, rather than selecting randomly at paint time. In other words, when you create the 'deck' array, build the entire deck so that every card knows what they are, before the user even begins to be dealt any cards from the deck. This way, there is no risk of them changing during gameplay. If you're only talking about 52 cards, or a small multiple of 52 cards, then the array is still pretty small and it'll be quick to randomise the entire array.

Alternatively, you could put a check on your "select random card" method that says something like this...

```
int cardValue = -1;

paintComponent(){
    if (cardValue == -1){
        cardValue = drawRandomCard();
    }
    // now paint it.
}
```

ie - restrict the `drawRandomCard()` to only run if the card doesn't already have a value.

Ultimately though, the best solution would be to completely separate the painting code from the logic - its bad coding practice for GUI activities like painting to be mixed in with programming logic.

Comment: Thank you to Greg, WATTO, and twain, your suggestion worked perfectly and I can move on to my next problem which I may post tomorrow.  Thank you all again!

Comment: No problem. If you're happy with an answer, please remember to 'tick' to accept it, so everyone knows your problem has been solved. Good luck with your game.